# regular expression on a id with numbers using webtrends

Tags: regex, webtrends

I want to get several hits on id's in 00.118.. 
So everything as in 00.1181, 00.1182, 00.1183 etc.

I couldn't find the regular expressions for this request. 
I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the expression for that:

```
/(00\.118[0-9]+)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/hD6fQ3/1